# "Qui meus tuus apud te locus, qui tuus velim ut meus"

Tags: syntax

In Letter XI of the apocryphal correspondence between Seneca and Saint Paul, the following passage is found

> Haut itaque te indignum prima facie epistolarum nominandum censeas, ne
> temptare me quam laudare videaris, quippe cum scias te civem esse
> Romanum. Nam qui meus tuus apud te locus, qui tuus velim ut meus. Vale
> mi Paule carissime.

I am having difficulty identifying the syntactic structure of this sentence:

> [Q]ui meus tuus apud te locus, qui tuus velim ut meus.

In particular, I do not understand why there are two correlated relative pronouns and how the syntax should be interpreted.

Answer (score 4):

The passage can be tricky to disentangle because it's highly elliptical. You have a parallel structure, but in Latin, you don't always need to repeat a verb or a subject, and then you have two forms of *esse* which also dropped (as they are wont to do). But they can be reinserted to make the syntax clearer.

Writing out just the basics less elliptically, you should get:

> [velim [ut locus [qui meus est] sit tuus]] (et) [velim [ut locus [qui tuus est] sit meus]]
>
> I wish that the situation which is mine may be yours and I wish that the situation which is yours may be mine.

Comment: It makes sense. So, you assume that "velim" governs both sentences. Do you think it's a type of syntactic structure that could be suitable for classical Latin (or, given that we're talking about Seneca, for Silver Age Latin)? Or does it betray a later syntactic organization (considering the historical forgery was likely composed in the 4th century)?

Comment: Also, where would you put that "apud te" in the first part of the sentence? With "meus" or "tuus"?

Comment: Yes, having the verb in the second clause only is [very much Classical](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17617/omitting-a-verb-when-it-is-the-same-for-both-parts-of-the-sentence). What is less Classical in style is the omission of any *sit*, at least according to [Allen and Greenough](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/verbs-and-subjects). (You should be able to find better links about when to omit the verb; these are just the first I found).

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu Oh, and to answer your second question, I think most translators keep it with *tuus*, "your situation with you." That would make an implied *apud me* in the parallel clause.